# Is there any continuous integration software with easy to write plugins?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, lotus-notes

I'd like to add a continuous integration tool to a project I'm working on. However, I'd like to be able to send the results of the build using Lotus Notes. I already have the Lotus Notes part covered, and I'd like you guys help me choose the right tool for this. I'd preffer something based on Java, but if something else's better, I won't mind.

Please only provide solutions where I can influence the build process somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)'s author actually wanted people to be able to contribute easily without access to the source repository. [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) has thus been designed for extensibility through plugins (it's not the only candidate but it's definitely a nice one). Have a look at the [Extend Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Extend+Hudson) section of its wiki.

These blog posts [Writing a Hudson plug-in (Part 1 – Preparation)](http://javaadventure.blogspot.com/2008/01/writing-hudson-plug-in-part-1.html) and [Writing a Hudson plug-in (Part 2 – Understanding m2 and freestyle projects)](http://javaadventure.blogspot.com/2008/01/writing-hudson-plug-in-part-1.html) might help too.

Answer (score 1):

Hudson is a CI solution that attracts plugins like bears to honey.

Answer (score 1):

Jetbrains [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity) has a plugin architecture that uses jar files - API [here](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Developing+TeamCity+Plugins). I love TeamCity (-:

[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) is explicitly extensible. Don't know any more about it than that because I'm really happy with TeamCity...